# Agregar información a iconos "apoyo" a los usuarios

Tags: javascript, html, c#

buen día.

Estoy agregando nuevas características a un portal que genera tickets de servicio.

quiero incluir información de ayuda para ciertos apartados, pero he estado buscando y no encuentro información de como agregar texto a los iconos al dar clic, o bien "posicionando" el mouse sobre el icono para que muestre un pequeño cuadro de texto como información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando con HTML, Javascript y C#; agrego un poco de código de los botones y el textbox que también necesitaría agregarle información al icono de ayuda.

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
 <br />
 <label><b>Link URL</b></label>&nbsp<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="http://ejemplo/formulario.aspx" data-ng-model="mUrlTicket_NR"/>
 <br />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Pruebas Soporte</button>&nbsp<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
  &nbsp<label><b>Archivos Adjuntos</b></label>
 <br />
 <br />
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="cArchivos">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="cArchivos"><b>Procesa Datos</b></label>&nbsp<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Fuentes De Datos</button><br />
  &nbsp<label><b>Archivos Adjuntos</b></label>
```

Comment: la propiedad [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label)?

Comment: gracias @infinit3Loop__ el atributo de titulo (title) en el objeto era lo que necesitaba

<i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="Ingresar la direccion URL que presenta la incidencia"></i>

igual ya revisé aria-label y me va a servir para otros campos que tengo contemplados.